# How to solve ERROR: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to update two columns of redshift table (table1) with columns of another redshift table (table2) based on certain conditions. I am getting the equijoin predicate error when running the below query.

```
UPDATE schema1.table1
SET col1 = sub.col3,
col2 = sub.col4
FROM (
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b.col3, b.col4 FROM schema1.table1 a LEFT JOIN schema2.table2 b 
ON ((a.col5 > b.col6) AND (a.col5 < b.col7))
)sub;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that Redshift cannot figure out which row you want to update.  There should be a WHERE clause indicating how the results from the from-select are matched up with the table being updated.

Here's an example from the Redshift docs:

```
update category set catid=100
from (select event.catid from event left join category cat on event.catid=cat.catid) eventcat
where category.catid=eventcat.catid
  and catgroup='Concerts';
```

Even though table "category" is referenced in the "from-select" Redshift needs the WHERE clause to align the result.  Also note that the reference to "category" inside the "from-select" needs to be aliased to avoid confusion.

Now let's look at your query (formatted):

```
UPDATE schema1.table1 SET col1 = sub.col3, col2 = sub.col4
FROM (SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b.col3, b.col4
    FROM schema1.table1 a
    LEFT JOIN schema2.table2 b
    ON ( ( a.col5 > b.col6 ) AND ( a.col5 < b.col7 ) ))sub;
```

You need a WHERE clause to allow Redshift to know where to apply each row of the "from-select".  This could be as simple as

```
WHERE table1.col1 = sub.col1 AND table1.col2 = sub.col2
```

but since I don't know your data model so this could be completely off.

There is also a hazard here in that using inequality joins in producing the FROM results could lead to a large number of rows and repeated updates.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is it possible to use inequality conditions in WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be clear what rows are being updated.  You can update col_a to 9 if col_b > 5 but writing it as update col_a to 9 if col_b > 5 and update col_a to 7 if col_b > 4 is ambiguous.